# Additional Steps to Deploy C# Teams Messaging Extension (Bot) to Azure?

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

I have used the [Bot Builder Teams messaging extension sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/51.teams-messaging-extensions-action) and successfully debugged the project locally on my machine using ngrok.  I then proceeded to follow the [Azure deployment instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp), and successfully deployed my bot project to Azure.

However, I cannot find instructions regarding what values need to change within my project to now use the assets within Azure.  I have [enabled the Teams channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/channel-connect-teams?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) on the Bot Channel Registration resource that was provisioned, and I tried updating the botId value within my project's manifest file to match that of the newly provisioned app registration.  But I'm still receiving an 'unable to reach app' message when sideloading the app in Teams.

Are there instructions regarding how/what to change within the project so it uses the Azure assets rather than my local ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To narrow down what's wrong, have you tried [using the Web Chat to test the bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#test-the-bot) ? If this works, then the bot is working fine in Azure and the issue is for local teams to reach Azure.

Also verify that you are using the [right AppID and Password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-overview?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#microsoftappid-and-microsoftapppassword).

Once you have verified that the bot is working in Azure, at the bottom of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/channel-connect-teams?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) page, you will see steps to get a url that you can paste to get the bot added in your local MS Teams instance. (quoting below for quick access)

> - Copy the https part of the code that is shown in the Get bot embed    code dialog. For example,
>   https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=28:b8a22302e-9303-4e54-b348-343232.
> - In the browser, paste this address and then choose the Microsoft    Teams app (client or web) that you use to add the bot to Teams. You
>   should be able to see the bot listed as a contact that you can send
>   messages to and receives messages from in Microsoft Teams.

Comment: Thanks @Rupendra!  My app ID and password were incorrect in the appsettings file, so I updated those and redeployed using steps 5.1 and 5.2 in the deployment article linked above.  Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be much change.  Because it's a Teams messaging extension, I'm not sure how useful the bot testing features are.  I tried both the Web Chat test and the embed code link.  They both work, in the sense that I'm presented with a chat bot, but neither have my action available via the compose message box so I can invoke it.  I suspect that might just be a limitation of the tools.

Answer (score 0):

I did finally get my bot working, but found several missing steps within the deployment documentation.  I have reported them in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/issues/2066), associated with the relevant documentation article.